# Best Way to Obtain Collaborators Through Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to obtain all current collaborators on a google sheet solely from the script editor. What is the best way to do this? I looked at the following but these only look like a way to set a key-value dict for properties. I want to automatically grab anyone who is shared on the google sheet and obtain their emails.

Again, I am trying to get a list of the emails of everyone who is **shared** on the google sheet. I will also take anyone who is a **collaborator**. This is different than the user just accessing the spreadsheet.

```
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
```

I really appreciate any help! I also would love to find your source of documentation so I can improve this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Rubén thanks for your comment. They are different questions. I have updated mine. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is written in the Google Apps Script documentation.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getEditors()

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getEditors()
```

where you can replace `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` with `.open(file)`, `.openById(id)`, `.openByUrl(url)` as it is a method for the `Spreadsheet` class.

The `PropertiesService` is something you can use to store a kind of global variable that you can use between script runtimes or functions.